# Xamarin not loading properly in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I installed Xamarin 4.3.0.742 over VS 2017 RC, installation went smooth but when I create a new Android blank app it fails to create solution giving this error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Also Xamarin settings in Options menu don't work, 'An error occurred loading this property page'.

And iOS settings gives off an 'XamarinIOSPackage did not load properly' alert box.

Anyone knows anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with VS 2017 RC and updates to Xamarin (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/6183/androidbuildsupportversion102-failed-to-install.html?childToView=9026#comment-9026). Once I updated Xamarin outside of VS 2017, Xamarin under VS 2017 RC stops working (e.g., the Options menu for Xamarin, build errors, etc). It sounds like that's what you're trying to do. If so, I recommend only updating VS 2017 RC through the "Extensions and Updates"; it'll pick up the latest for Xamarin for VS 2017. --Ken

Comment: Indeed, I installed Xamarin the old way (by downloading .msi installer).

Did you get the same errors as me?

Do you mean I should use the new VS Installer to install Xamarin? because it's not available in Extensions and Updates.

Comment: Install Xamarin when you install VS 2017, there's an option for that. Once you install VS 2017, update from now on using Extensions and Updates menu item. Xamarin seems to be updated with the VS update. I don't recall all the problems but it was painful because prior to the Dec 15 update of VS, Xamarin was not working well, even in a clean virtual machine. But, once I went to the latest VS 2017 RC release from Dec 15, Xamarin projects now work. It doesn't look like there's a separate Xamarin update for VS 2017, like there was in VS 2015 through the Options menu, but hopefully that will change.

Comment: I am running the latest 15.0.26014 update, I will try and install Xamarin through VS Installer (Xamarin workload, I guess that's what you mean).

Answer (score 0):

With the latest VS 2017 RC and latest Xamarin.iOS on my Mac, I get:

> The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.3) on the Mac XXX (X.X.X.X) is
>   not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS 10.4. Double click here to
>   select a new server.

There are no newer Xamarin.iOS versions available on Xamarin's site for download.  I believe this means there's no current way to get Xamarin fully working for iOS development via VS 2017 RC right now.

Comment: Could you get the downloaded Xamarin MSI package to work with VS 2017?

Comment: You can't use the MSI package with VS 2017.  Use the Visual Studio 2017 Installer and check the appropriate boxes in there instead.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem by copy and pasting android SDK APIv23 (copying full sdk folder may take more time, so you only need to copy android-23 under android-sdk\platforms directory)

to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android directory,

and its working fine and after i changed the sdk location to my old location